# React hook renders [object object]

Tags: reactjs

I am new in React and I am not sure what I do wrong. I am trying to use useEffect and save list in useState. But I am getting [object object] back.

I am building simple weather app and I managed to save 1 result into useState, but now I wanna have 3 constant cities showing weather on page load, not depending on what user enteres. Here is the code

```
  const [query, setQuery] = useState('');
  const [weather, setWeather] = useState({});
  const [weatherConst, setWeatherConst] = useState([]); <-- not working

  useEffect(() => {
    fetch(`${api.base}group?id=3413829,6618983,2759794&units=metric&APPID=${api.key}`)
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(result => {
      setWeatherConst(result)
      console.log("new list" + result)})
  }, []) <-- not working



  function apiCall() {
    fetch(`${api.base}weather?q=${query}&unit=metric&APPID=${api.key}`)
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(result => {
        setWeather(result)
        setQuery('')
        console.log(result)
      })
  }
```

When I console log "new list" i get [object object], but when I run link by itself in browser I get list of 3 cities back

[Image of result getting back](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kzxKa.png)

Comment: What does the actual content of the response look like?

Comment: Just uploaded the picture, so you can take a look

Comment: `"new list" + result` is string concatenation, which will implicitly call `result.toString()`, which gives `"[object Object]"`. Use `console.log("new list", result)` instead, or if you want to make a more readable string form try e.g. `JSON.stringify(result, null, 2)`.

Comment: Wow thanks, im stupid, im mixing a lot of technologies, yikes

Comment: @jonrsharpe That's the answer! You should post it! :3

Comment: It's pretty much a typo, I'd suggest just deleting it - the [mre] is `console.log("foo" + {})`.

Comment: If I may ask, why when I wanna see result in html <h3>{weatherConst[0].name}</h3> like this, I get weatherConst is undefined?

Comment: Because the initial value of `weatherConst` is `[]`, which you set it to, and `[][0]` is undefined.

Comment: So, how can I get list I saved into weatherConst to show in html? I mean, for starters to target 1 element of list. In useEffect i used setWeatherConst(result.list), shouldn't that save list into it?

Comment: Conditionally render `{weatherConst.length && <h3>{weatherConst[0].name}</h3>}` which will avoid the initial undefined state, or assign an initial value to weatherConst `useState([foo])`

Comment: If I do so, then I can just get [0].name, [1].name is undefined..., gosh this is so confusing

Answer (score 3):

Here is a quick snippet illustrating the sequence.

We set the initial state to `[]` as you have.

On the first render we check `state.length` and because our initial array is empty it renders `<h2>Loading...</h2>`.

The `useEffect` runs and waits 1 second before calling`setState([...loadedState])` which triggers a render (the useEffect cleanup runs here and clears the timer).

We check `state.length` again and now because our array is no longer empty we render `state[0].name`, `state[1].name`, `state[2].name`. (For a known index or limited number of indexes this is ok, but you'll usually want to use `state.map()`)

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/babel-standalone/6.26.0/babel.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/babel">
  const { useState, useEffect } = React
  
  const loadedState = [{name: 'foo'},{name: 'bar'},{name: 'baz'}]
  
  function App() {
  const [state, setState] = useState([])
  
  useEffect(() => {
    const timer = setTimeout(() => {
      setState([...loadedState]);
    }, 1000);
    
    return () => clearTimeout(timer);
  },[])
  
  return (
    <div className="container">
      {state.length ?
        (<div>
          <p>{state[0].name}</p>
          <p>{state[1].name}</p>
          <p>{state[2].name}</p>
         </div>) : (<h2>Loading...</h2>)
       }
    </div>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
</script>

<div id="root"></div>
```

**Note**

The answer to your actual question was given in the comments by  jonrsharpe.

`"new list" + result` is string concatenation, which will implicitly call `result.toString()`, which gives `"[object Object]"`. Use `console.log("new list", result)` instead, or if you want to make a more readable string form try e.g. `JSON.stringify(result, null, 2)`.

Answer (score 1):

If you would like another example of explanation:
I would like to explain by simple words. When we use "useEffect" or "setSmth (created by useState hook)"  hook we need to understand that this is not a simple function which we just call. This is some kind of async function which calls when it needs.
So, for example :

```
     useEffect(() => {
    axios
      .get(
        "https://api.oceandrivers.com:443/v1.0/getForecastPoints/cnarenal/language/en"
      )
      .then((res) => res.data.data)
      .then((res) => {
        setWeather(res);
        console.log(weather);
      })
      .catch((e) => {
        console.table(e);
      });
  }, []);
```

We can not see results in "console.log(weather)" , because setWeather(res) didn't finish work. We see result only after render of component. So, if we create a list:

```
   let weatherList = weather.map((el) => {
    return <li key={el.name}> {el.name} </li>;
  });
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <ul>{weatherList}</ul>
    </div>
  );
```

we'll see all information that we need.

If you would like to see all code: https://codesandbox.io/s/wonderful-feynman-n0h39?file=/src/App.js:503-677

Sorry for my English. If I said smth wrong tell me please, I'll be very appreciated!